# SVN Post-Commit Hook Script to get the exact commited path

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, svn-hooks, post-commit-hook

I need a SVN Post-Commit hook script to run a vbs script only if the changes happened in particular path. below is the repository folder structure,

```
                    -Virtualize
                         +trunk
                         +branch
                         -tags
                            VirtualAssets/....
```

In which I am committing the files in below path. https://example.com/svn/PARAVIRTQ2/Virtualize/tags/VirtualAssets/DEV/PCM/CSRCall/CSRCall_1/files1, files2 etc..,

I want to run a vbs script from the Post commit Hook Script (.bat) only if the changes happened in https://example.com/svn/PARAVIRTQ2/Virtualize/tags/ path.

```
 ECHO %REPOS% >%tmpBuildFile%
 ECHO %REV% >%tmpBuildFile%
 FOR /F "tokens=*" %%D IN ('%SVNLOOK% dirs-changed %REPOS% -r %REV%') DO ( 
 set DIR=%%D
 ECHO Changed Directory is : %DIR%   
 if "%DIR%"=="%DIR:Virtualize/tags=%" (
   ECHO Found the directory to build in UCB 
   cscript post-commit.vbs %DIR% %author% %REV%
 ) else ( 
   ECHO Not found the Directory to do build 
 )
)
```

Comment: What have you tried so far, and in what way did it not work? Hint: you should be using `svnlook changed`

Comment: @alroc - Nein!!! `svnlook dirs-changed | grep ...`

Comment: @alroc I have updated the query with my sample script. Can you see if I am missing out anything